# How to loop a function into VueJs methods?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to loop this method so I can have a carousel that doesn't stop changing the image and text related.
Here is the method:

```
mounted() {
    this.rotateImage()
  },
  methods: {
    rotateImage() {
      setTimeout(() => this.rotateImage(), 5000) // call this function again in 5 seconds (recursive)
      setTimeout(() => this.$refs.container.changeImage(), 1500) // after 1.5s, begin image transition
      this.$refs.overlay.changeText()
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Hi @Phil i can't loop the rotateImage() function. So once all the image in the array are shown, the image slider stop. And I don't want it to stop after looping just once. I want to repeat the function.

Comment: Can you post some demo or something on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)

Comment: There is no loop in rotateImage, you are having a recursion and there is no argument passed to the rotateImage

Comment: Hi @Viney, guys here is the link on CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loop-ud0we?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset the `currentIndex` to 1 when it reaches the last item of that array

ImageContainer.vue

```
changeImage() {
  if (this.currentIndex === this.images.length - 1) 
    this.currentIndex = 1;
  else this.currentIndex += 1;
}
```

TextOverlay.vue

```
changeText() {
  if (this.currentIndex === this.texts.length - 1) 
    this.currentIndex = 1;
  else this.currentIndex += 1;
}
```